# Solve the question and give the explanation

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, steady-state

[image: Solve and explain why.]

I did understand the first part of the question where current is supposed to be 1 A. **However I'm in a fix over the second part whether or not to take the resistors in parallel or series**. Could someone let me know why.

Comment: We're not here to do your homework.  In light of that, you should change the title to something more meaningful.

Comment: I already had the answer. It's just that some of my friends have confused me on what was to be done.

Comment: Then show your answer so we can confirm that it is correct or not.

Comment: All I need to know why I shouldn't take the resistors in series.

Comment: **Don't** answer your own question, use **edit** and / or comment on it. Please learn how to use this site properly like everyone else.

Comment: I'm new to Stackexchange,so it will be a while before I'm used to it.

Comment: On top of that, you seem to assume that you shouldn't take the resistors in series, and want us to explain why. How can we explain something that is wrong?

Comment: That is no excuse, then just browse the site for a while and see what is OK and what is not, also read the Tour (help => Tour) !

Comment: At position 1, the value of current was 1 A. After that, after  10ms,  I got a current of 0.6321 A.

Comment: Then when the inductor begins to discharge, I got 0.4683A at t=15 ms and at t=20ms,  I got 0. 3469A.

Comment: *I'm new to Stackexchange,so it will be a while before I'm used to it.* Exactly as long as it takes you to read the text right next to the answer entry field, or the field you can enter questions in. lame excuse.

Comment: I've made my account less than a week ago and it's been a really busy week for me. But I will surely explore Stackexchange more.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm using the app and there is no way to delete my answer.

Comment: *Heavy hints:* time constant = L/R ,  resistors in a series circuit are added together.

Comment: *I've made my account less than a week ago and it's been a really busy week for me* And how does that concern us ? Stop making excuses, man-up and say: "Sorry, should have read the guidelines, will do better next time." Then you're most welcome on SEE. When you ask a question **properly** there's also a very large chance that you will quickly get a **proper** answer.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that others learn from reading problems like this, so I'm not so focused on the idea that you must learn this. I can use your question as a foil for the benefit of others, as well. If you get it, fine. If not, fine.

By the way, the problem description wasn't complete. It should have included the point that the circuit has been operating since \$t=-\infty\$ and that the switch is opened at \$t=0\$.

In that case, the value of \$I_{t=0}=\frac{10V}{10\Omega}=1A\$ does arrive.

Here is that first situation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwN6eO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then the second situation is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frSC9k.png)</sup>

You should be easily able to see that \$R_1\$ is now in series with \$R_2\$. I really don't know why that part of this problem is confusing you. You have an instant just prior to the switch changing which is one very simple situation and then, just after the switch changing to a new position you have another very simple situation.

It simply should *not* be difficult. The above two situations are not hard to imagine. Besides, there is no question in my mind that if you are taking classes on this, the teacher will have already walked you through this at least once. If not, I'm sorry for you and you'll have to develop the ideas on your own (as I have had to.) Either way, you will definitely need to get past this barrier to move on. So spend some time and work carefully through it until you can fully apprehend the ideas without much difficulty.

Assuming you know some basic calculus, the equations are easy. Remember that \$V_{L_t} = L\cdot\frac{dI_{L_t}}{dt}\$ and take note that \$R_x=R_1+R_2\$. So:

\$V_{L_t} = V_{R_t} = -I_{L_t}\cdot R_x \;\;\; \therefore I_{L_t} = -\frac{V_{L_t}}{R_x}\$, and

\$V_{L_t} = L\cdot\frac{dI_{L_t}}{dt}\$, so \$\;\;\;\therefore I_{L_t} = -\frac{L\cdot\frac{dI_{L_t}}{dt}}{R_x}\$

Follow the algebra below:

\$I_{L_t} = -\frac{L\cdot\frac{dI_{L_t}}{dt}}{R_x}\$

\$I_{L_t} = -\frac{L\cdot dI_{L_t}}{R_x\cdot dt}\$

\$\frac{R_x}{L} dt = -\frac{dI_{L_t}}{I_{L_t}}\$

\$\frac{dI_{L_t}}{I_{L_t}}=-\frac{R_x}{L} dt\$

Now integrate to solve for finite values:

\$\int \frac{dI_{L_t}}{I_{L_t}}=\int -\frac{R_x}{L} dt =- \frac{R_x}{L}\int dt = - \frac{R_x}{L}t\$

\$ln\left(I_{L_t}\right) = - \frac{R_x}{L}t + C_0\$

\$I_{L_t} = e^{-\left(\frac{R_x}{L}t + C_0\right)} = A_0\cdot e^{-\left(\frac{R_x}{L}t\right)}\$, where \$A_0=e^{-C_0}\$

At \$t=0\$, it is now obvious that \$A_0=10A\$, so the final equation is:

\$I_{L_t} = 10A\cdot e^{-\left(\frac{R_x}{L}t\right)} = 10A\cdot e^{-\left(250\cdot t\right)}\$, as \$R_x=25\Omega\$ and \$L=100mH\$

Learn to do that in your sleep.